# How do you get the gambling password in Monkey Island 2?

Tags: monkey-island-2-lechucks-revenge

At one point in the game, you're trying to guess a password to get the next winning number on the gambling wheel. It's a series of hand combinations. Is there a simple formula to determine what numbers the various hand gestures correspond to?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not sure I remember correctly but I'll give it a try.

The correct answer is always the amount of fingers he shows in his example.

For example: If he says "If this is 3", and he holds up 4 fingers, then he holds up another number of fingers and asks "what is this?", the correct answer would be 4.

To make it clear, he shows you two sets of fingers and the number of fingers he holds up the first time is the correct answer.

So there is not really any formula or anything, and it doesn't matter what he says the first fingers correspond to, you just have to look at how many fingers he is holding up and that will be the answer to the next set of fingers.

Comment: The first time I played the game (all those years ago!) I thought it was a sort of meta-puzzle where you had to save, guess incorrectly and be told the answer, then re-load. I was really proud I'd figured that out :/

Comment: @Alex That's how you can finish Zak McKracken skipping the lottery part...